# crawled data has invalid char like ''?'' in some places/

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to crawl data from a news website for a link preview on the hover effect. The site is in Turkish language. The data I crawled to display has invalid characters on rendering.

[image: image showing invalid char on rendering]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example there is no way to see how you are reading the content or crawling the site, so there is no way to know how to help.

Comment: Welcome to text encodings. Computers handle everything as as long series of two-value series that we call ones and zeros by convention. Mapping that binary data to human scripts requires a book of rules called encoding. Today's de-facto standard is UTF-8 but there've been many other encodings, many of which are still being used. Can you please edit the question and add a code sample on how you scrape sites?